# force refresh of cmake script in subsequent runs of 'make'

Tags: c++, cmake

In my `cmake` script I determine the current date and hand it to my `c++` program source, so that the build date is compiled into the program. The problem is, that in subsequent runs of `make`, in which `cmake` is acutally not run at all, the date is not updated.

How can I force `cmake` to refresh it's variables and recompile the program by using `make` only? Alternatively: What is the best way to compile the build date into the binary?

The `cmake` script contains this:

```
INCLUDE(Today)
TODAY(DATE)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(
    ...
    -DBUILD_DATE=\"${DATE}\"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use a custom target to execute whatever you want. custom targets are always considered out of date and run on every build.

```
add_custom_target(RerunCmake ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
add_dependencies(YourTarget RerunCmake)
```

this works fine with makefiles. but visual studio for example will nag you after every build asking to reload the project because the project files changed on disk.

maybe it would be better to make a custom target that just updates a header file with the correct date so cmake doesn't rerun on every build

Comment: +1 for suggesting custom targets. The bigger problem however is probably how to get the date back to the Makefile without triggering a rebuild of the complete project (as, for example, your header file solution would).